# How can i block users from streaming facebook videos

Tags: wireless-networking, firewall, draytek

I have a Draytek vigor 2925VNPlus and I have been able to block users on my WiFi from going to YouTube. However I don't want to block Facebook as a whole I just want to be able to block the videos so they don't stream. Is there like a common URL Facebook videos use? Please how do i achieve this?

Comment: Related: http://superuser.com/questions/783300/block-facebook-video-on-router

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can. Facebook offers TLS (HTTPS), so you can't tell what your users are doing on Facebook.